# python no module named 'A' __init__ vs package

Tags: python

I have looked up several answers on google but none of them made my problem correct.

I made my python file in directory `A`

in my `__init__.py` I have `app = Flask(__name__)`

When I want to get app from other file I use:

```
from A import app
```

but error says `no module named 'A'` so I changed to

```
from __init__ import app
```

now it works

Can anyone tell me why `from A import app` does not work?

Comment: Where is the file that you're doing the import in relative to the `A` package?

Comment: Sounds like you're inside the package directory (at the same directory level as `__init__.py`, while you should be one up for `from A import app` to work. Or, alternatively, have the package properly installed, and work from an unrelated directory.

Comment: im using ubuntu and my A is locate at /var/www/B/A

Comment: my init.py is locate /var/www/B/A/init.py

Comment: and also wonder A is a package why they say no module named A?